# Can't convert DateTime to string in C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, type-conversion, razor-pages

Hi i'm trying to make a reservation page. If someone makes a reservation that date gets saved in the database and will also be showed on their page. The type of the column 'dayid' is date in postgresql. In razor pages C# i used the type DateTime for variable Dayid. I need to convert the dayid value from database to a string. But i don't know how to solve this error:
"No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments"
Here is the code

```
public List<ReservationModel> ShowReservation()
        {
            var cs = Database.Database.Connector();
            List<ReservationModel> res = new List<ReservationModel>();
            using var con = new NpgsqlConnection(cs);
            {
                string query = "Select dayid, locationid FROM reservation";
                using NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, con);
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    using (NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            res.Add(new ReservationModel { Dayid = dr["dayid"].ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), Locationid = dr["locationid"].ToString() });
                        }
                    }
                    
                    con.Close();
                }
            }


            return res;
        }
```

Comment: What type of `dr["david"]` is?

Comment: Try assigning dr["dayid"] to a variable and double check that it's a datetime. It's likely object. I'd cast it to DateTime before calling ToString to be able to use the formatting parameters.  
Also consider a possibility where you get DateTime from your model and avoid casting.

Comment: I suspect the problem is down to `dr["dayid"]` boxing the value, so you're actually accessing it as `object`.

Comment: Alright i tried to do DateTime Dayid = dr["dayid"] above the while loop but it tells me cant convert object to System.DateTime

Answer (score 5):

The compile-time type of the `NpgsqlDataReader` indexer is just `object`, and the `object.ToString()` method is parameterless. You need an expression of type `DateTime` to call the `ToString` overload that you want.

You *could* cast to `DateTime` instead:

```cs
while (dr.Read())
{
    res.Add(new ReservationModel
    {
        Dayid = ((DateTime) dr["dayid"]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"),
        Locationid = dr["locationid"].ToString() 
    });
}
```

(Or find the column index and call `dr.GetDateTime(...)`.)

However, I'd encourage you to change your model (`ReservationModel`) to keep the value *as* a `DateTime` instead of converting it to a string at this point anyway. In general, it's a good idea to keep data in its most natural data type for as much of the time as possible, only converting it to/from text at boundaries.

Comment: Hi i tried your code but then i got this error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'

Comment: @anonD: Well I was *assuming* that your `Dayid` property is of type `string`, given your previous code. Is that not the case? Perhaps it's *already* a `DateTime`? In which case, why were you calling `ToString` at all?

Comment: Yes the variable DayId in the reservationmodel was of type DateTime. because in the database that column is of type date. I want this date to show on the page thats why i want it to convert into a string.

Comment: @anonD: So you need to do the conversion to a string later. You can't assign a `string` to a `DateTime` property, and it's better not to anyway. In your `ShowReservation()` method you should just cast to `DateTime`, e.g. `Dayid = (DateTime) dr["dayid"]` and then perform appropriate text conversions in your view.